# kick off background task and return immediately

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method called `DownloadFileAsync(url, Func<RemoteFileResponse, Task> onDownloadFinished)` which performs the following:

- Checks the cache and if found, returns the cache immediately and starts a background task to see if the cache needs to be updated
- If not found, returns null and kicks off a background task to download the file asynchronously
- After the file is downloaded it calls back on the *onDownloadFinished* handler.

This feels dirty to me as I need to perform the download on a background thread but I can't await it because I want to be able to return the cached file right away. The problem is that I lose any exception context if I do this.

Some options I can think  of:

- Use the IProgress interface to report back the cached file and then when the download is finished report back the downloaded result.
- Split the method into two calls (one to get the cached file) another to download/update (not a preferred way since I want to keep my interface to one method).

Was wondering if anyone had any other suggestions of how I could do this?

Pseudo code for my method:

```
Task<IFile> async DownloadFileAsync(url, Func<RemoteFileResponse, Task> onDownloadFinished)
{
   var cache = await CheckCacheAsync(url);

   // don't await this so the callee can use the cached file right away 
   // instead return the download result on the download finished callback
   DownloadUrlAndUpdateCache(url, onDownloadFinished);

   return cache
}
```

Comment: Please include the return type of `DownloadFileAsync(url, Func<RemoteFileResponse, Task> onDownloadFinished)`

Comment: Just return a `Task`, rather than using a callback delegate.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I updated the question with pseudo code of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Servy I am returning a task, the problem is I don't want to await the download because I want the callee to be able to use the cached file (if it exists) right away

Comment: The callback seems odd to me, why is it a `Func<..., Task>`, the fact that the callback must return a task is confusing. To me a callback would be some kind of `Action` and most likely a `Action<IFile>` or  a `Action<RemoteFileResponse>` based on your code example.

Comment: @JustinHorst The method can just return a `Task`. If the item is cached, then that task will be completed very quickly and have the cached value.  If it's not cached, then the task will simply take longer to complete.  The caller has the luxury of not needing to know or care if the value comes from the cache or not, just as you'd set it up when writing a synchronous method.

Comment: @Servy my requirement is that it returns the cached result but still goes and fetches the image (if it's newer than what's in my cache). So I want to return the cache right away, go check if my cache is still fresh and if I download something newer, return the new image on the callback

Comment: @ScottChamberlain the Func<..., Task> allows to me pass in an async Action

Comment: @JustinHorst Then just always return two tasks, one for the cached version and one for the uncached version, rather than one task and one callback.

Comment: why do you want to check if there is a new version each and every time the resourc is accessed? even if you do it in the the background, with minimal impact to the response time it is still a waste of cpu time/async ports. a cleaner approach would be to separate these 2 concerns and do the checking and updating of the cached version periodically.

Comment: @neo112 I tend to agree that I would like to separate these concerns, however my hope was to create an API where the call-ee would not have to worry themselves about where the data was coming from (the cache or the server). Also, because of the nature of my application, the data is likely to change very often and it's paramount that I always have the most recent version of the file.

Comment: @JustinHorst If you have frequently changing data in which you must always have the most up to date version, then simply don't cache it.  If you can't ever use the cached version, don't bother caching it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your cache is an in-memory cache, then it's easier to cache the tasks rather than their results:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Url, Task<IFile>> cache = ...;

Task<IFile> DownloadFileAsync(url) // no async keyword
{
  return cache.GetOrAdd(url, url => DownloadUrlAsync(url));
}

private async Task<IFile> DownloadUrlAsync(url)
{
  ... // actual download
}
```

Logically, the `GetOrAdd` is doing this (but in a thread-safe and more efficient manner):

```
if (cache.ContainsKey(url))
  return cache[url];
cache[url] = DownloadUrlAsync(url);
return cache[url];
```

Note, however, that this will cache the complete task, so download exceptions are also cached.

Comment: Stephen thanks for the response! However I have the following requirement. EVEN if the result is in the cache, I still want to make a webrequest to see if the version I have is still fresh (i.e. I send up a Etag up with my next request and redownload the image if it's not fresh anymore). Also, my cache is in a different service (not in memory).

Comment: @Stephen, I think it's better to wrap ```DownloadUrlAsync(url)``` into ```new Lazy<Task<IFile>>(() => DownloadUrlAsync(url))```, otherwise during concurrent calls with the same key the value factory for the ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd will be evaluated multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new class FileRetriever that would contains the cached file and a Task that would be completed when the latest revision of the file is retrieved from the server.

Something like this:

```
public class FileRetriever
{
    public IFile CachedFile { get; private set; } 

    // Indicate if the CachedFile is the latest version of the file. If not, 
    // then LatestFileTask will complete eventually with the latest revision 
    public bool IsLatestFileVersion { get; private set; } 
    public Task<IFile> LatestFileTask { get; private set; } 

    public FileRetriever(IFile file)
    {
        IsLatestFileVersion = true;
        CachedFile = file;
        LatestFileTask = Task.FromResult(file);
    }

    public FileRetriever(IFile file, Task<IFile> latestFileTask)
    {
        IsLatestFileVersion = false;
        CachedFile = file;
        LatestFileTask = latestFileTask;
    }
}
```

To initialize the FileRetriever object, you would first check your cache to see if the file is already present.

```
Task<FileRetriever> async GetFileRetrieverAsync(url)
{
    IFile file = GetFileFromCache();
    if (file == null)
    {
         // File is not present in cache. Download it asynchronously and await it 
         // before returning the FileRetriever
         IFile file = await DownloadUrlAndUpdateCacheAsync(url);
         return new FileRetriever(file);
    }

    // File is present in cache but a new revision might be present on server. 
    // Start the download task but don't await for its completion. 
    Task<IFile> task = DownloadUrlAndUpdateCacheAsync(url);
    return new FileRetriever(file, task);
}
```

And then, you would use it like this:

```
var fileRetriever = await GetFileRetrieverAsync(url);
DoSomethingWithFile(fileRetriever.CachedFile);

if (!fileRetriever.IsLatestFileVersion)
{
    // A new revision of the file might be present on the server.
    // Wait for the download before updating the UI with the new file revision
    fileRetriever.LatestFileTask.ContinueWith(t => DoSomethingWithFile(t.Result)); 
}
```

Please note that I didn't tested this and error handling should be added in case where the download of the file fails.